# Linq: the best overloaded match has some invalid arguments

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I do a linq to sql query to get a list:

```
var list1 = db.Table1.Where(a => a.item == "Widgets").ToList();
```

Now I want to get a list from another table using the results of list above:

```
var list2 = db.Table2.Where(a => list1.Contains(a.GUID)).ToList();
```

So far this all works as expected.

Now I want to do a query where I find all rows in another DB table that have GUIDs from my list2

```
var list3 = db.MyTable.Where(a => list2.Contains(a.GUID)).ToList();
```

The data types are all the same in the three tables so I know those match. But I get the best overloaded match has some invalid arguments?

Comment: Could you post the exact exception?

Comment: Error 12 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test1.Data.Models.Table1>.Contains(Test1.Data.Models.Table1)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Then says: Error 13 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'Test1.Data.M‌​odels.Table1' but all my field types are long in the model class (in the db they are bigint)

Comment: What's interesting is that if I first do var myGUIDs = list2.Select(x => x.GUID).ToList(); and then use that into my list3 query lambda it works fine (but then why don't I have to do that between list1 and list2?

Comment: I would suggest you to not use var, but use the real type, this way you should see what the problem is. I'm surprised that `var list2 = ...` does even work, because list1 shouldn't be a List<long>, but list1.Contains(someLong) works...

Comment: I edited my answer, which should explain why your code is not working and how to more easily dig into it. Please accept if this explains and solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Where`-clause in your third line:

```
var list3 = db.MyTable.Where(a => list2.Contains(a.GUID)).ToList();
```

EDIT: Okay, this was only a type and the question was edited, see new answer below.

---

Looking at your exception

> System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(Test1.Data.M‌​odels.Table1)' has some invalid arguments

We can see that list2 is of type `List<Test1.Data.Models.Table1>`, yet you try to run `list2.Contains(long)`. You have to change

```
var list2 = db.Table2.Where(a => list1.Contains(a.GUID)).ToList();
```

to

```
var list2 = db.Table2.Where(a => list1.Contains(a.GUID)).Select(a => a.GUID).ToList();
```

Then list2 should be of type List.

I am personally not a big of `var` because you cannot extract the exact type of a variable from source code. If you change your `var`*s* to "real" data types you may see your problem far easier.

Comment: That was typo in the question (thanks for seeing it). I edited the question. The initial problem is still the same.

Comment: Yes -- doing what you said I will pass the right type to the lambda in list3 query. For me I do need the rest of the fields in list2 so I just do what you said but I get my full list2 for my use and I also get the Select(a => a.GUID) like you said by doing a quick myGUIDs = list2.Select(x => x.GUID).ToList(). So now I have myGUIDs as a list instead of list2 to use in my list3 query and all is well. Thanks!